# Expectation of Ball in Box

Tags: probability, expectation

I have a very short and simple question but this is very vital because it starts off my solution so I need to understand this puzzling concept (for me at least)! I have labelled that specific step with "WHY??".

*QUESTION:*

**Suppose n balls are distributed at random into r boxes. Let $X_i$ = 1 if box i is empty and let $X_i$ = 0 otherwise.**

**Compute E[$X_i$].**

*SOLUTION:*

Let $A_i$ be the event that box i is empty.

Then,

**$X_i$ = $1_{A_i}$**

Hence,

**E[$X_i$] = E[$1_{Ai}$] = P[$A_i$] **WHY??**

...

the further solutions are pretty straight forward

BUT this step...

I have no idea what E[$1_{Ai}$] means. Why is there a 1?

Thank you so much for your help! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected value of a variable with only finitely many possible values $v \in V$ is, by definition, the sum
$$\sum_{v \in V} vp(v)$$
hence, in your scenario,
$$E(X_i) = (1)P(A_i) + (0)P(A_i') = P(A_i)$$
where $A_i'$ is the complement of $A_i$.

With regard to the notation $1_{A_i}$, it denotes the *indicator* *function* on the set $A_i$, which is the function which has value $1$ at points of $A_i$, and zero at all other points.

$\qquad$https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

It's so named since it *indicates* by its one-or-zero value at a given point whether or not the point is in the given set.

Comment: ahh I see... that's so much clearer! what about this? **$X_i$ = $1_{A_i}$** what does this mean?

Comment: Presumably, $1_{A_i}$ is the function on the sample space which takes the value $1$ at points of $A_i$, and zero at all other points.

Comment: so if the question now says that $X_i$ = 2, $X_i$ = $2_{A_i}$, is that right? also, does that mean that the $0_{A_i}$ was hidden and not written? since it's 0

Comment: The value $0$ is on the complement of $A_i$. But I think the notation $1_{A_i}$ is overkill for such a simple scenario.

Comment: As far as $X_i = 2$, there's no reason for it. The whole idea of letting $X_i = 1$ on $A_i$ and zero on $A_i'$ is, presumably, to calculate the expected number of balls in box $i$.

Comment: oh I see... haha overkill... thank you so much quasi!! I understand now! ah... right right... #binary